# MATLAB search and Zip

Tags: matlab, zip

I want to search a directory and sub-directories for all `.doc` files and zip them all into one file using MatLab. If I use the `zip()` matlab function it only allows for one root directory.
 `ZIP(ZIPFILENAME, FILES, ROOTDIR)` .

1) How do I recursively search the sub directories?

2) How do I add all the zip files into one folder?

Would it be best to search for, and move all `.doc` files into a temporary folder, then zip them from that location?

Comment: why do you want to zip files in MATLAB? It's kind of strange.

Comment: Yeah, this is much more suited to a bash script.

Comment: I wish to use a simulink block which will use a  callback to an .m  script that will collect all model report doc files and zip them into one folder.  Also I am not using Linux I am on a Windows pc

Answer (score 1):

First, use `dos(...)` to dir for all .doc files, including all subdirectories (option `/S`), but only display the filenames, no additional information (option `/B`). The first output argument is the returned status, the second output argument is the string returned on the command line:

```
[~, filenamesFromDos] = dos('dir *.doc /B/S');
```

Second, extract the filenames from that command as a cell array. Filenames are seperated by the newline (`\n`) char and the path could potentially contain spaces, thus `'Whitespace',''`:

```
filenames = textscan(filenamesFromDos,'%s','Delimiter','\n','Whitespace','');
```

`filenames` is then a `<1x1 cell>`, containing a `<Nx1 cell>` of filename strings. With this `<Nx1 cell>` we can call the builtin matlab function `zip(...)`:

```
zip('zip_file.zip',filenames{1});
```

Done.